# His wishes still haven't come true

Tags: adverbs

Can I use "still" before "haven't" or after "haven't" or at the end of the sentence?

1. "His wishes still haven't come true."
2. "His wishes haven't come true still."
3. "His wishes haven't still come true."

Comment: #1 is the natural position for ***still***. #2 and #3 aren't idiomatic with ***still*** - they're natural constructions for ***yet***, which usually comes *after* the auxiliary verb (***haven't*** in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "His wishes still haven't come true."

This is the usual and correct way of saying it - even though the corresponding affirmative sentence "His wishes still have come true" sounds unusual (at least in British English).

> "His wishes haven't come true still."

This may sometimes be heard - in casual conversation, someone might add on the word "still" as an afterthought, but it isn't the best way of saying it.

> "His wishes haven't still come true."

This sounds very odd - even though "His wishes have still come true" (in the affirmative) is fine and is in fact the normal way of saying it in the positive.

The only time I can imagine saying "His wishes haven't still come true" would be in contradicting someone who had previously said they would still come true: "You told me that if he did *x*, his wishes would still come true!  Well, he did *x*, and his wishes haven't still come true!"  This would more or less make sense colloquially, but it would be better to say simply "haven't come true" and omit "still".

> "Still his wishes haven't come true."

This is OK without the comma, but there is a risk of confusion with the other sense of "still" (="nevertheless").  It differs from that in intonation and in punctuation, but it is not the most usual way of saying it.